# ASP Visual Basic Code Crashing...Help Much Required

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

I am trying to insert data into a oracle database 
The data gets inserted and updates the database, however the page throws an error each time the insert statement finished even though the database was updated?

How can i fix this bug? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">
    <h1>Connie's Control Panel</h1>
        <div class="header">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Supplier You Want To Update:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name= "supplierName" required ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Supplier Name Updated:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name= "supplierNameUpdated" required></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Supplier Address Updated:</td>
                        <td><input type="type" name="supplierAddressUpdated" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Supplier Rating Updated:</td>
                        <td><input type="type" name="supplierRatingUpdated" required></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">


            </form>

            <%
                    Dim objConnection
                    Dim objRecordset
                    Dim objUpdateSet

                    Dim nameCheck
                    Dim nameUpdate
                    Dim addressUpdated
                    Dim ratingUpdated


                    nameCheck = Request.Form("supplierName")
                    nameUpdate = Request.Form("supplierNameUpdated")
                    addressUpdated = Request.Form("supplierAddressUpdated")
                    ratingUpdated = Request.Form("supplierRatingUpdated")

                    Set objConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

                    With objConnection
                    .ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=DELETED;User ID=n011266e;Data Source=stora;Persist Security Info=True"
                    .Open


                    Set objRecordset = .Execute("SELECT * FROM Suppliers")


                    if nameCheck<>"" then

                        Do while (Not objRecordset.eof)

                        Set objRecordset = .Execute("UPDATE Suppliers SET SupplierName =" & "'" & nameUpdate &"'" & "WHERE SupplierName =" &"'" & nameCheck&"'")




                        objRecordset.MoveNext

                        Loop

                    end if

                    End With
                    objConnection.close
                    Set objConnection = Nothing
                    Set objRecordset = Nothing
                    Set objUpdateSet = Nothing
                %>




        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="stock.asp" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-white icon-pencil"></i> Enter Stock</a>
            <a href="stockReport.asp" class="btn btn-success">Stock Report</a>
            <a href="supplier.asp" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-white icon-pencil"></i> View Suppliers Details</a>
            <a href="newSupplier.asp" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-white icon-pencil"></i> New Supplier</a>
            <a href="inputSupplier.asp" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-white icon-pencil"></i> Edit Supplier</a>
        </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What error is thrown?  Where?

Comment: Also never provide an actual password in your question.

Comment: Try closing your recordset before you close your connection.  And - you're not using VBA but vbscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need not do "SELECT * FROM Suppliers"  and Do while loop

you can directly execute

```
"UPDATE Suppliers SET SupplierName ='nameUpdate' WHERE SupplierName ='nameCheck' "
```

may be your getting error because your executing on  "objRecordset = .Execute(.. ) " which already has select.